# Why isn't my Javascript function working when trying to a display a list of objects with a Rails backend?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple page of Charity objects that each have a button for 'Add to list' (1). This button, when clicked, should allow the user to then click on a list icon (2) and view all Charitites the user has added. This was written with a Javascript frontend and a Rails backend.

[My charities page with numbers showing each button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGdAx.png)

When I click 'Add to list' my terminal shows the following output, and I do not see any errors come across in the page console (using F12):

```
Started GET "/users/2" for ::1 at 2021-05-30 11:53:04 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
   (0.5ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:9:in `show'
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:9:in `show'
  UserCharity Load (4.5ms)  SELECT "user_charities".* FROM "user_charities" WHERE "user_charities"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:9:in `show'
  Charity Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "charities".* FROM "charities" INNER JOIN "user_charities" ON "charities"."id" = "user_charities"."charity_id" WHERE "user_charities"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `show'
Completed 200 OK in 46ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 10.1ms | Allocations: 3335)


Started POST "/user_charities" for ::1 at 2021-05-30 11:53:04 -0400
Processing by UserCharitiesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"2", "charity_id"=>"1", "user_charity"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "charity_id"=>"1"}}
  UserCharity Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "user_charities".* FROM "user_charities" WHERE "user_charities"."user_id" = ? AND "user_charities"."charity_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 2], ["charity_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_charities_controller.rb:3:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/user_charities_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_charities_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  Charity Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "charities".* FROM "charities" WHERE "charities"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_charities_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  UserCharity Create (3.7ms)  INSERT INTO "user_charities" ("user_id", "charity_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 2], ["charity_id", 1], ["created_at", "2021-05-30 15:53:04.893530"], ["updated_at", "2021-05-30 15:53:04.893530"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_charities_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (26.3ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/user_charities_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  Charity Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "charities".* FROM "charities" INNER JOIN "user_charities" ON "charities"."id" = "user_charities"."charity_id" WHERE "user_charities"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_charities_controller.rb:11:in `create'
Completed 200 OK in 128ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 32.6ms | Allocations: 10975)


Started GET "/charities" for ::1 at 2021-05-30 11:53:05 -0400
Processing by CharitiesController#index as */*
  Charity Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "charities".* FROM "charities"
  ↳ app/controllers/charities_controller.rb:6:in `index'
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 22.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Allocations: 2326)
```

When I click the list icon nothing happens. I see no errors in the F12 console and there is no output in my terminal.

Below is my Javascript:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
const CHARITIES_URL = `${BASE_URL}/charities`;
const LIST_CHARITIES_URL = `${BASE_URL}/list_charities`;
const LISTS_URL = `${BASE_URL}/lists`;
const USERS_URL = `${BASE_URL}/users`;
const USER_CHARITIES = `${BASE_URL}/user_charities`;

const signUpForm = document.querySelector('.container');
const addUserForm = document.querySelector('.signup-form');
const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('.input-text');
const signUpBtnPhrase = document.querySelector('.sign-up-btn');
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('main');
const listContainer = document.querySelector('.list-container');
const listBtn = document.querySelector('.list-button');
const logoutBtn = document.querySelector('.logout-btn');
// const sortOptions = document.querySelector('.sort-menus');

let loggedIn = null;
let signedUp = false;
let charitiesObj = {};

function hideSignUpForm() {
  signUpForm.style.display = 'none';
}

signUpForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(USERS_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: inputFields[0].value,
      email: inputFields[1].value,
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(function (object) {
      localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', object.data.id);
      renderLoggedInUser(object.data);
    });
});

listBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  listContainer.style.display = 'block';
});

listBtn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  listContainer.style.display = 'none';
});

logoutBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.clear(loggedIn);
  window.location.reload();
});

// sortOptions.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
//   fetch(BASE_URL + `/${e.target.value}`)
//     .then((res) => res.json())
//     .then((charities) => renderCharities(charities));
// });

function renderLoggedInUser(loggedIn, userCharityIds) {
  let welcome = document.querySelector('#welcome-container');
  welcome.innertText = ' ';
  welcome.innerText = `Welcome ${loggedIn.name}!`;
  fetchCharities(userCharityIds);
}

function fetchCharities(userCharityIds) {
  fetch(CHARITIES_URL)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((charities) => renderCharities(charities, userCharityIds));
}

function renderCharities(charities, userCharityIds = []) {
  const mainContainer = document.getElementById('main-container');
  mainContainer.innerHTML = '';
  charities.forEach((charity) => {
    mainContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="card">
          <img src=${charity.image} class="charity-avatar" />
          <h2>${charity.name}</h2>
          <p><em>${charity.category}</em></p>

          <button onClick=addToList(event) data-charity-id="${charity.id}"> ${
      userCharityIds.includes(charity.id) ? 'Remove from list' : 'Add to list'
    } </button>
          </br>
        </div>`;
  });
}

function addToList(event) {
  if (!userId()) {
    alert('Please login to continue');
    return;
  }

  fetchUser().then((res) => {
    fetch(USER_CHARITIES, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user_id: userId(),
        charity_id: `${event.target.dataset.charityId}`,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        renderLoggedInUser(
          res,
          res.data.attributes.charities.map((x) => x.id)
        );
      });
  });
}

function fetchUser() {
  if (userId()) {
    let id = userId();
    return fetch(USERS_URL + '/' + id).then((res) => res.json());
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function checkForUser() {
  if (localStorage.loggedIn) {
    let id = localStorage.loggedIn;
    fetch(USERS_URL + '/' + id)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(function (res) {
        renderLoggedInUser(
          res.data.attributes,
          res.data.attributes.charities.map((x) => x.id)
        );
      });
    hideSignUpForm();
  } else {
    signUpForm.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

const userId = () => localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

checkForUser();
```

Below is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyCharities: Find your favorite charities! </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
</head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="charity-header">
        <img src="https://www.agwinery.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/charity-header-txt-e1313029035674.png" alt="charity-font" border="0">

    <div class="sort-menus">

        </div> 

        <div class="sort-menu-children">
     
        </div>

        <div class="list-button"><button id='list-btn'><img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/add-list.png"></button>
            <div class="list-container">
            
            </div>
        </div>

    <main id="main-container">
    
    </main>
        
        </div>
    </div> 
    
    <div id="welcome-container">
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="container">
        <form class="signup-form" >
            <h3> Sign Up</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" class="input-text">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" class="input-text">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" class="submit">
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="logout-btn">
        <button id="logout">Logout</button>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is my user_charities controller in Rails:

```
class UserCharitiesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user_charity = UserCharity.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], charity_id: params[:charity_id])

    if user_charity
      user_charity.destroy
    else
      user_charity = UserCharity.create user_id: params[:user_id], charity_id: params[:charity_id]
    end

    render json: UserSerializer.new(user_charity.user).serialized_json
  end
end
```

And below is my charities controller in Rails:

```
class CharitiesController < ApplicationController
  require 'pry'
  
      def index
          charities = Charity.all
          render json: charities, except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
      end 
  
      def show
        charity = Charity.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if charity
          render json: charities, except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
          render json: sort
          render json: find
        else 
          render json: {message: "Charity not located."}
        end 
      end 
  
      private
  
      def charity_params
          params.require(:charity).permit(:name, :image, :category)
      end 
  
  end
```

I have been stuck on this for days. Any insight or help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

There may be an error in your function `renderCharities` when you define the button `addToList`.

You attach the event handler like so `onClick=addToList(event)` but this effectively executes the function directly (for each button) and assignes it's return value (`undefined`) to your `onclick` which does nothing. You should do it like this:
`onClick=addToList`. This only sets the reference to the `addToList` function without executing it.

By the way, this line `welcome.innertText = ' ';` contains a typo at `innertText` and is useless because you set the `innerText` in the next line anyway.

**EDIT:**

If you mean that your `list-button` does nothing, and if this code is all you have for this button then it is no surprise. There is no `click` handler for this button (you may not need one if you only want to display your list on mouse hover) and additionally the `listContainer` is never filled with data.

```
listBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  listContainer.style.display = 'block';
});

listBtn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  listContainer.style.display = 'none';
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

Seems that there is something twisted with your `querySelector` that might lead to unexpected errors/behavior.

```
const signUpForm = document.querySelector('.container');
const addUserForm = document.querySelector('.signup-form');
```